How to adjust a WPGridbuilder Facet to show backordered product on a Woocommerce site
By default, WPGridbuilder's "Stock" filter does not consider "On Backorder" as a stock status by WooCommerce, it considers it as "In Stock".
I want to create a facet which differentiates between these stock statuses, so that the end user can filter the product by "in stock", "On Backorder", or "Out of Stock".
The developer says,

Backordered is not considered a stock status by WooCommerce; it is considered as In Stock. Therefore, the indexer value will be the one from WooCommerce.
If you need to change the indexed facet value, you can use this PHP filter: https://docs.wpgridbuilder.com/resources/filter-indexer-row/

I'm just a beginner with PHP, so I'm afraid this doesn't make much sense to me.
The closest I've come to solving the problem is by creating a custom field in Woocommerce which defines each of these things separately. WPGridbuilder is able to pick up the new custom field, so this sort of works.
// Update custom meta field _in_stock based on stock level and backorder status
function update_in_stock_meta_field($post_id) {
    // Get the product object
    $product = wc_get_product($post_id);

    if (!$product) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the stock quantity
    $stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();

    // Check if backorders are allowed
    $backorders_allowed = $product->get_stock_status();

    // Set the _in_stock meta field based on stock quantity and backorder status
    if ($stock_quantity >= 1) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_in_stock', 'In Stock');
    } elseif ($stock_quantity <= 0 && $backorders_allowed === 'onbackorder') {
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_in_stock', 'On Backorder');
    } else {
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_in_stock', 'Out of Stock');
    }
}

// Hook into the WooCommerce save_post action
add_action('save_post', 'update_in_stock_meta_field');

The problem with this code is that it requires the product to be manually updated for any changes to take effect. So if I have 5 items left in stock, and a customer purchases all 5, it will still be listed as "In Stock" until the product is updated on the backend (most likely during an inventory update, which occurs once a day). So this isn't a very accurate way of keeping up with stock status as it will frequently be out of date.
Any pointers to get me headed in the right direction?
Thanks in advance.

Wordpress uses actions to 'hook into' specific actions, and WooCommerce uses/extends this system too. At the moment you are updating the stock information on save_post actions. WooCommerce has actions too, for example woocommerce_payment_complete for orders that have completed (payed or failed) their payment. You can use these hooks too update the stock too, but be aware that it can be tricky with stock (because when do you take it out of stock, and what happens if two orders are competing for the last product). I hope this points you in the right direction! The question was well worded.
